# Weird shifting spaces in the middle of code

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've got a really weird problem with PhpStorm - I've used it for years now, and it's been fantastic. Recently though, it's started putting weird spaces in the middle of lines where there aren't any:

[image: [http://grab.by/Rrcs]]

But then when I click into the line, it suddenly shifts the spacing (here I clicked immediately before the `"` character - *after* a block of spacing):

[image]

If I press backspace, the `y` is deleted.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this to happen, and how to fix it?

Edit: I'm running PhpStorm 2016.2 on OSX 10.11.5

PhpStorm 2016.2
Build #PS-162.1121.38, built on July 12, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: IDE version? It should be fixed in 2016.2

Comment: @LazyOne forgot to mention that - I'm using 2016.2 :/

Comment: So ... what version you are on: 2016.1.2 .. or 2016.2 (released yesterday/today) ? When I said "fixed" I meant this one -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19970 (not sure how appropriate it is to your case now though...)

Comment: @LazyOne interesting, wasn't aware of that. I've just updated to 2016.2 and it's still happening. I've tried opening a new project, invalidating the caches and restarting but it's still happening :/

Comment: Well .. file a bug report ticket then (do not forget to attach your `idea.log`) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with Webstorm version 2016.3 OS X

It is the **Font/Size** combination in Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > Font

For me the culprit was '**Source Code Pro**' font at size **14**. Any other size at that font (...,12,13,15,16...) goes back to normal (no weird spaces)

I suspect there are other font/size combinations that could cause similar symptoms.

---

In short: **Change your font or size in Preferences > Editor > Color & Fonts > Font**

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same thing with 2016.2.

To fix it...

I deleted the PhpStorm2016.2 application. Then, I deleted several files (listed below) associated with the install.

~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.2

~/Library/Caches/PhpStorm2016.2

~/Library/Logs/PhpStorm2016.2

Finally, I re-install Phpstorm2016.2. Imported my settings. And everything was back to normal.